# Iterate over a Dataframe column using common value in a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
List=[1,2,3,4,5]

df = col_1   col_2   col_3
         1           8          10
         2           7           11
         1           9            6
         1           4            7
         2          10           12
```

Problem.

I want to get the all records that are in `col_1` and the list but I want to do it group at a time.

Example,

The first index of list is `1`, take the index compare it to `col_1` find the match below and process it.

```
df = col_1   col_2   col_3
         1           8          10
         1           9            6
         1           4            7
```

Take the next index `2`, find the match below and process it

```
df = col_1   col_2   col_
         2           7           11
         2          10           12
```

Iterate till there is no matches between the list and the `df`.

Comment: How your final df looks like?

Comment: {x : y for x , y in df.groupby('col_1')}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the list and create a new dataframe by matching the list iteration value with col_1.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in mylist:
     new_df = df[df['col_1'] == i]
     # do stuff with your new dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in a for loop, and maintain the df structure:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,8,10], [2,7,11],[1,9,6],[1,4,7],[2,10,12]])
for val in my_list:
    print(df[df[0]==val])
```

I'm printing the resultant dfs above, but you can obviously do whatever you want to them. You would change the 0 in `df[df[0]...]` to whatever column you want to match on

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic dataframe indexing and `df.empty`. The loop will break when the first non-match occures.

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for n in li:
    filtered_df = orig_df[orig_df['col_1'] == n]
    if filtered_df.empty:
        break
    # rest of logic with filtered_df
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this, instead of lambda function you can pass your custom function that process each part of dataframe. Here the lambda function is only filtering values in "col_1" that are in lst. One benefit of this method is you will get new dataframe from you result at the end

```py
lst=[1,2,3,4,5]
result = df.groupby("col_1").apply(lambda x: x[x["col_1"].isin(lst)])
```